# Required Selenium Test Cases for Yahoo Login Form

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium. Anybody can please write down Selenium Test Cases for yahoo login form. It will be really appreciated, if someone help me.

Comment: I take it this is homework? Or is there a reason you need to test the yahoo login form?

Comment: Are you using the Java, C#, Python, or HTML API? Selenium 1 or 2?

Comment: -1, because the question is too specific to be useful for the community. Here's the quote from the [site help](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "You should avoid "What test cases should I test for _ ", as the answers will be considered too localised and will change depending on the testing context."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too specific to be of general interest.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to start learning selenium is to use the [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp) to record a sequence of steps in the browser; then export it to a WebDriver script, and refactor it into a robust testcase.

Comment: can you give me any example and post here?

Comment: I think you need to read the [Selenium IDE docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp), and have a go yourself.

Answer (score -2):

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/config/login?.src=fpctx&amp;.intl=us&amp;.done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=username</td>
    <td>your yahoo email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=passwd</td>
    <td>Enter your password here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=.save</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```